# Show table data on another page in a table HTML

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is the following:
I have created an array from a table I already have and stored the column I want into an array, and then stored it in the localStorage using JSON.stringify:

```
function createArray(){
        var arrayPlayerName = [];
        var count = 1;
        while(count<=playerNum){
            arrayPlayerName.push(document.getElementById('playertable').rows[count].cells[1].innerHTML);
            count++;
        }

        localStorage.setItem("playerNameArray", JSON.stringify("arrayPlayerName"));
    }
```

(playerNum is a variable with a fixed number used in other methods, and the "getElementById" works).

After that I want to show this data in another table in another HTML doc.
So, the following is my HTML code:

```
<table class="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="row">
            <th colspan="3">Array List</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And this is the script:

```
    var storedPlayerArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("playerNameArray"));

    tablegenerate (storedPlayerArray);

    function tablegenerate (list) {
        for(i=0; i<playerNum;i++){
            var $formrow = '<tr><td>'+list[i]+'</td></tr>';
            $('.myTable').append($formrow);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.. thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am calling the createArray function with a button, and I'm navigating to the second page with another button. The second page should load directly.

EDIT2: I have revised that the array is being stored and called properly on the second page, so the issue is now on the "tablegenerate" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I think I found the problem try this:

```
var storedPlayerArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("playerNameArray"));

function tablegenerate (list) {
    for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++){
        var $formrow = $('<tr><td>'+list[i]+'</td></tr>');
        $('.myTable').append($formrow);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    tablegenerate (storedPlayerArray);
})
```

---

You have an issue in your `createArray` function.. You are running `JSON.stringify` on a string instead of the array you want to store.

Change this:

```
localStorage.setItem("playerNameArray", JSON.stringify("arrayPlayerName"));
```

To this:

```
localStorage.setItem("playerNameArray", JSON.stringify(arrayPlayerName));
```

Comment: Wow you're right... just changed that right now. The table still isn't showing up on the second page though :(

Comment: I am getting now the error "Cannot read property 'append' of null"

Comment: I'll need to see some more code to be able to understand the problem. Can you please add the player table HTML? and what ever else code you believve might be relevant

Comment: I think that the problem I'm having right now is that the code to properly populate the table on the second page is not correct, therefore resulting in the error I mentioned eariler.
I am currently investigating on how to do this properly, so I think that the question is different from the original - I think that the problem now resides in the
`function tablegenerate` code.

Comment: ok so what does the stored array look like? give me an example and i'll to help you fix the tablegenerate function

Comment: Thanks! So, the stored array is a standard array with names inside - about 25 elements inside.
Lets just say:
`storedPlayerArray[0] = David
storedPlayerArray[1] = Pet`
And so on - I hope this was what you were looking for

Comment: Check out my new solution: I made multiple changes to your code

Comment: Yep it worked! Now I only have to arrange it so that it displays out neatly; thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help